# How do I change the default request timeout for Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am currently using Selenium 2.0a2 in Java to access the Internet using an `HtmlUnitDriver` instance. The problem I am facing is that, when I attempt to access slow websites, the request times out. How can I increase the time that WebDriver waits before throwing a timeout exception?

Comment: Is the exception on the `Get()` for the page or when waiting for an element on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(new VisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("whatever")));

10 is the timeout is seconds.